# CollectionView choppy scrolling when loading admanager banner ads

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, smooth-scrolling, google-ad-manager

I have a collection view with n sections and m rows. The number of sections and rows are fetched from an API.  Typically 18 sections with 10 rows each. Each cell item is just one `UIImageView` and two `UILabel`s.

It all was working smooth scrolling until I added `google ad manager banner ads` in the cells. For that I just created a new section with number of item 1 in that section. And gave the size of cell the full width and respective height of the banner ad. I followed the `UITableView` example of google ad manager to implement in `UICollectionView`.

But now when ever the collection view is loading, or reloading through `UIRefreshControl`, for about 1-2 seconds it gives choppy scrolling behaviour. After that scrolls smoothly.

```
extension HomeVideosViewController {
    
    func loadBannerAd() {
        // call ad requests
        
        let filteredIndices = self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource.indices.filter { (index) -> Bool in
            if self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[index].section_type == "banner_ad" {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        
        for index in filteredIndices {
            
            if let bannerAd = self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[index].datasource.first as? BannerAd {
                
                // create banner ad object
                let bannerView: DFPBannerView!
                
                if bannerAd.is_mid_ad == true {
                    bannerView = DFPBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeLargeBanner)
                } else {
                    let frame = { () -> CGRect in
                        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                            return self.view.frame.inset(by: self.view.safeAreaInsets)
                        } else {
                            return self.view.frame
                        }
                    }()
                    let viewWidth = frame.size.width
                    bannerView = DFPBannerView(adSize: GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(viewWidth))
                }
                
                // save index as tag for banner ads
                bannerView.tag = index
                bannerView.adUnitID = bannerAd.ad_code
                bannerView.rootViewController = self
                bannerView.delegate = self
                
                bannerView.load(DFPRequest())
                
                // replace bannerAd with banner view
                var updatedBannerAd = bannerAd
                updatedBannerAd.requestBannerView = bannerView
                self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[index].datasource = [updatedBannerAd]
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let homeSection = self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[bannerView.tag]
            
            // replace bannerAd with banner view
            if let bannerAd = homeSection.datasource.first as? BannerAd {
                
                var updatedBannerAd = bannerAd
                updatedBannerAd.receivedBannerView = bannerView
                updatedBannerAd.adRequestComplete = true
                homeSection.datasource = [updatedBannerAd]
                
                // replace home section with banner ads
                self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[bannerView.tag] = homeSection
                
                // check if ads requests are complete
                self.checkForIncompleteAds()
            }
        }
    }
}

extension HomeVideosViewController: GADBannerViewDelegate {
    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd for index : \(bannerView.tag)")
        
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
        }
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
        didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        
            let homeSection = self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[bannerView.tag]
            
            // replace bannerAd with banner view
            if let bannerAd = homeSection.datasource.first as? BannerAd {
                
                var updatedBannerAd = bannerAd
                updatedBannerAd.adRequestComplete = true
                homeSection.datasource = [updatedBannerAd]
                
                // replace home section with banner ads
                self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource[bannerView.tag] = homeSection
                
                // check if ads requests are complete
                self.checkForIncompleteAds()
            }
    }

    func checkForIncompleteAds() {

        let homeBannerAdsNoCompleted = self.homeVideosDatasource.datasource.filter { (homeVideosSection) -> Bool in
            if homeVideosSection.section_type == "banner_ad" {
                if let bannerAd = homeVideosSection.datasource.first as? BannerAd {
                    return !bannerAd.adRequestComplete
                }
                return false
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }
        
        if homeBannerAdsNoCompleted.count == 0 {
            // Reload CollectionView
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To narrow down the issue I tried commenting where I was placing the banner ad inside the cell. But the choppiness was still there.

Then I tried commenting where `addBannerViewToView` to see if placing the ad in datasource was making the issue, but still this method was not the issue.

Next I tried commenting `checkForIncompleteAds()`, but this was also not the issue.

Most probably the culprit here is `loadAds()`. When I commented this out the scrolling was smooth. But i'm not sure what could be the potential fixes for this. I cant even put it on background thread.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try reloading collectionView i.e. `self.collectionView.reloadData()` also after ads view is loaded, not only when after `homeBannerAdsNoCompleted.count == 0`

```
//Reload CollectionView
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It can't be moved to any other method I think. `checkForIncompleteAds()` is checked if ads are loaded or not. `homeBannerAdsNoCompleted.count == 0` tells that there are no ads that are no completed... that means all ads are loaded (either loaded successfully or failed with error).

Comment: I mean you are facing this issue when the ad is loaded successfully right. So after ad loading, reload the collectionView. Now, you are reloading only when there are no ads.

Comment: I'm reloading the collectionview when ads response is received, whether they load successfully or failed with error. `Now, you are reloading only when there are no ads.` - this statement is not right.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem exactly lies in requesting the ads (`bannerView.load(DFPRequest())`), this is called on the `main` thread and here in my code calling it in a loop (of 4 for now) blocks the `main` thread.

Instead of calling it in a loop Google recommends calling first request, then after completion of that request, call second request. That is there should be at most one active request on main thread.

So I added two properties:

```
    var adsToLoad = [GADBannerView]()
    var loadStateForAds = [GADBannerView: Bool]()
```

`adsToLoad` keep the ads to be requested.
`loadStateForAds` keeps the ad vs bool value to know which ads are successful and which ads are failed.

Then this method requests ads one by one.

```
    func preloadNextAd() {
      if !adsToLoad.isEmpty {
        let ad = adsToLoad.removeFirst()
        let adRequest = GADRequest()
        ad.load(adRequest)
      }
    }
```

`preloadNextAd()` is called first when ads are loaded into `adsToLoad`.

```
                // load banner ads
                self.loadBannerAd()
                self.preloadNextAd()
```

and then from GAD delegates methods.

```
  // MARK: - GADBannerView delegate methods

  func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ adView: GADBannerView) {
    // Mark banner ad as succesfully loaded.
    loadStateForAds[adView] = true
    // Load the next ad in the adsToLoad list.
    preloadNextAd()
  }

  func adView(
    _ adView: GADBannerView,
    didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError
  ) {
    print("Failed to receive ad: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    // Load the next ad in the adsToLoad list.
    preloadNextAd()
  }
```

There is still a little choppiness but greatly reduced.